# Iterate list with next() and previous() correctly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, iterator

I need an iterator where I can navigate between the items of the list with next() and previous().

ListIterator doesn't work for me because it works with cursor logic like below.

```kotlin
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
val iterator = list.listIterator()
println(iterator.next()) // 1
println(iterator.next()) // 2
println(iterator.previous()) // 2
```

According to the example above, output I want `1,2,1`

Is there any other method Android provides (Kotlin, Java) except ListIterator for this?

Or how can I do it with safe and clean Kotlin code?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. Calling `next(), next(), previous(), previous()` will result in `1, 2, 2, 1`. The "cursor" is between the elements so to speak.

Comment: ^ this. And no, there's nothing else in the standard library. Just call `previous` an additional time.

Comment: I spelled it wrong, sorry. Not "expected output", it should have "output I want". I updated.

Comment: This might be an XY problem because it sounds so bizarre. What's the actual use case? Maybe you could create an iterator that works with the concept of a *current* item instead of a position between items and has functions for `getCurrentAndMaintainPosition()`, `getCurrentAndIncrementPosition()` and `getCurrentAndDecrementPosition()`

Comment: In this situation I would just call _previous_ twice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what a `ListIterator` would do if it worked the way you suggest:

```
val i = listOf(1,2,3,4,5).listIterator()
while (i.hasNext()) {
  println(i.next()) // prints 1-5 in order
}
while (i.hasPrevious()) {
  println(i.previous()) // prints 4-1, and then... NoSuchElement?
}
```

Then consider what `next()` would now print.

That behaviour is clearly broken. So, change your expectation and use the existing `ListIterator` implementation as it is, in it's correctly implemented way.

Comment: Thank you Jorn. I have no problem with the logic of ListIterator. It doesn't work exactly as I want it to. I'm just looking for a solution similar to it. That's why I mentioned ListIterator.

Comment: Any other implementation would be equally broken if it worked this way, even if it's not called `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is inconsistent, not only with the documentation:

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list
> in either direction, modify the list during iteration, and obtain the
> iterator's current position in the list. A ListIterator has no current
> element; its cursor position always lies between the element that
> would be returned by a call to `previous()` and the element that would
> be returned by a call to `next()`. An iterator for a list of length n
> has n+1 possible cursor positions, as illustrated by the carets (^)
> below:

```
                       Element(0)   Element(1)   Element(2)   ... Element(n-1)
cursor positions:    ^            ^            ^            ^                  ^
```

but with the common logic of the nature of an iterator.
One you travelled in a given direction, the exact same length reverse traversal must give you the exact reverse sequence. If not you would be very surprised (the exact reverse sequence of "I visited New-York, then Tokyo", is "I visited Tokyo, then New-York").

So if you really need to get 1,2,1, you just have to add an extra reverse traversal at the beginning:

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5);
val iterator = list.listIterator();
println(iterator.next());     // 1
println(iterator.next());     // 2
iterator.previous();          // ignore first element of the backward traversal
println(iterator.previous()); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Is there any other method Android provides (Kotlin, Java) except ListIterator for this? ..."*

You can encapsulate *[ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html)*, and intercept the *next* and *previous* calls.
Just add the methods as needed.

This is technically a *[wrapper class](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)*.

```java
class ListIterator2<E> {
    final ListIterator<E> iterator;

    ListIterator2(ListIterator<E> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    E next() {
        return iterator.next();
    }

    E previous() {
        iterator.previous();
        return iterator.previous();
    }
}
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
ListIterator2<Integer> iterator = new ListIterator2<>(list.listIterator());
System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.previous());
```